# Bundle Install dependency error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, bundle

I'm currently running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.1.1

Getting this message when using `bundle install`:

```
In Gemfile:
coffee-rails (= 4.0.1) ruby depends on
  railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) ruby

rails (= 3.2.16) ruby depends on
  railties (3.2.16)
```

I tried `gem install railties` and still got the same thing.

I'm sure there's an easy fix that isn't so obvious for a beginner like me. What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe trying a newer version of Ruby might work. It might be worth a shot.

Comment: Would that mess with my current install of Rails?

Comment: Show your Gemfile, or remove `coffee-rails` version in it, if such exists.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by uninstalling rvm + rbenv (which may have been conflicting) + rails and basically started over, setting rvm to use 2.1.2 as the default ruby. 

bundle install worked well and no weird coffee-rails error that I was having before.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your gemfile.lock , & again do bundle install , i think rails 4.1.1 not properly install. do

```
 gem install rails -v 4.1.1
```